# proto_text/gen_proto_text_functions.runfiles [for host] failed

Tags: tensorflow

command:

```
bazel build --config=opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package --verbose_failures
```

Error:

```
tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/proto_text/BUILD:33:1: Creating runfiles tree bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/tools/**proto_text/gen_proto_text_functions.runfiles** [for host] failed (Exit 1): build-runfiles failed: error executing command 
  (cd /mnt/lustre/sjtu/users/mkh96/.cache/bazel/_bazel_mkh96/44343823a879bff37be22e42f904ace4/execroot/org_tensorflow && \
  exec env - \
  _bin/build-runfiles bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/tools/proto_text/gen_proto_text_functions.runfiles_manifest bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/tools/proto_text/gen_proto_text_functions.runfiles)
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 337.846s, Critical Path: 0.12s
INFO: 1 process, local.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
srun: error: lianyungang: task 0: Exited with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is the more evident compiling instructions](https://gist.github.com/HawkAaron/575fc12e6598a7a5f93423ee9677847f)

And if you want to install tf bindings, please refer to [this guide](https://gist.github.com/HawkAaron/093f128d4f51b417d7885f839091d41a).